# In the java DBCP connection pool - what is an idle connection?

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

A colleague at work insists that a DBCP idle connection is a connection that has lain unused for 30 minutes.

I believe a dbcp idle connection is a connection that is in the pool available to be borrowed, and an active connection is one that is borrowed.

Looking through the code I found no reference to 30 minutes or other magic values and a cursory glance through the code for assuring minidle does not show any such logic.

If he is correct can you please back that up with a code or documentation reference. For the complete answer I would like it answered for both DBCP 1.1 and 1.6.

Comment: I think you assumption is probably more correct.  An connection which has been idle for a period of time might be suitable for reduction, depending on how the pool grows/shrinks connections...

Comment: You are correct. What your colleague is talking about is an *expired* connection, and the age isn't necessarily 30 minutes, it is configurable. In fact 30 minutes is far too long to hold a connection in the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html

`minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` is set to exactly 30 minutes by default and it's the

> minimum amount of time an object may sit idle in the pool before it is
>   eligable for eviction by the idle object evictor (if any).

Reading the entire configuration page doesn't 100% explicitly say that you're correct and your colleague is wrong but I still think you'll agree when you read it. :)

Comment: Sure it does: that's how long the connection can *stay* idle before being discarded.

Comment: Sure it does. A connection older than 30 minutes ceases to exist altogether. Ergo it can't be described as 'idle'. It is idle *while waiting to expire.*

Comment: OK - I see where the communication broke down, he is talking about 'waiting to expire' as if they are idle.