# Java Connection Pooling - addObject() query

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I'm using the apache commons packages to create a connection pool in my java application. The MAXACTIVE value is set to 0 and the MINACTIVE value is set to 1. Using the setMaxWait() method I'm setting the wait time to 30 seconds i.e. once the getConnection() method is called it waits for 30 seconds and if the connection is unavailable it throws an exception (unable to get idle object).

Now inside the catch block I'm calling the method addObject() and getConnection() in succession. I'm able to get a Connection object despite the fact that the MAXACTIVE parameter is set to 0. How is this possible?

```
try {
    connection = datasource.getConnection();                        
} catch (Exception e1) {
    try {
        datasource.addObject();
        connection = datasource.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        /* Ignored */
    }
}
```

What happens to the pool when the addObject() method is called and how are the various parameters like MAXACTIVE and MINACTIVE affected when a new idle object is created in the pool?

Comment: You should probably show your code instead of describing it with words.

Comment: @assylias Done!

Comment: What version of Commons Pool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If I look at addObject() in Apache Commons Pool 2.4.2 (latest) in class `GenericObjectPool`

It create **Idle** pool object which is added to `idleObjects`. Max active effect `allObjects` which is a different object.

To control idle connection see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396624/in-the-java-dbcp-connection-pool-what-is-an-idle-connection).

```
@Override
    public void addObject() throws Exception {
        ...
        PooledObject<T> p = create();
        addIdleObject(p);
    }

/*
 * All of the objects currently associated with this pool in any state. It
 * excludes objects that have been destroyed. The size of
 * {@link #allObjects} will always be less than or equal to {@link
 * #_maxActive}. Map keys are pooled objects, values are the PooledObject
 * wrappers used internally by the pool.
 */
private final Map<IdentityWrapper<T>, PooledObject<T>> allObjects =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<IdentityWrapper<T>, PooledObject<T>>();

private final LinkedBlockingDeque<PooledObject<T>> idleObjects;
```